# Can the nonlinear hydrodynamic forces be neglected when a capsized ship is righting?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

Can the nonlinear hydrodynamic forces be neglected when a capsized ship is righting?
Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Do **not** repost a closed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some detailed information this is impossible to answer.

In general your inclusion of non-linear hydrodynamic forces probably depends a lot on your righting moment and sea-state conditions.  If the dominate forces are the linear ones (large righting moment), then smaller effects from friction, turbulence, etc. on an irregular structure is less important.  However if the linear forces are marginal due to steepness/period/size of waves, strength of wind, low righting moment, etc. then they become more critical and could prevent the vessel from righting -- or at least from righting on first roll or in a predictable way.